# Is this a property of Normed Vector Spaces?

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $X$ a normed vector space on $(\mathbb{K}, + , . )$.

Is the following assertion true?

Any $x$ of $X$ can be written as $x = \alpha a$ ,
$\alpha \in \mathbb{K}$ , $a \in X$ with $||a||_X=1$

Does anybody has a proof to validate or invalidate it?

Comment: If the norm function $\|\cdot \|$ is a map into $\mathbb{K}$ then $\alpha := \|x\| \in \mathbb{K}$ and $a := \alpha^{-1}x$.

Comment: @smangerel indeed, $||.||_X : X \rightarrow \mathbb{K}$. But your comment doesn't seem to prove anything.

Comment: it provides an explicit construction of $\alpha$ and $a$ for $x$ given, which is precisely what you're asking...

Comment: @smangerel  Yes, you were totally right. Sorry..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\forall x\in X$ $\alpha = ||x|| \in \mathbb{K}$. Then $y = x/||x||\in X$, $||y||=1$. If $x=0$, take any $||a||\in X$ with norm $1$.

Answer (score 0):

If $x=0$ then take any vector $a$ such that $\|a\|=1$ and $\alpha=0$ and you get $x=\alpha a$. If $x\ne0$ so let $\alpha=\|x\|^{-1}$ and $a=\frac{x}{\|x\|}$ and again $x=\alpha a$.

Comment: Thank you very much, I gave it to Pavel Yudaev as he was faster, but I find yours even clearer.